# Finding the formulae in terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The cost, $£C$,  of building a circular pond is proportional to the square of its diameter, $d$ meters. A pond with diameter $2$ meters costs $£52$.

Find the formulae for $C$ in terms of $d$.

Okay so I got $C=d^{52}$ but the mark scheme says $C=d^2$ can someone talk me through why they answer is that?

Comment: "The cost of building a circular pond is proportional to the square of its diameter". Could you please tell us what you mean by that statement?

Answer (score 3):

You need to solve for the constant of proportionality: you are told that $C=kd^2$, and are given an additional piece of information that $52=k \times 2^2$. This tells you that $k=13$, so the answer should be $C=13d^2$

(Sorry but $C=d^{52}$ is certainly not correct!)

Comment: What is 'K' referring to?

Comment: $k$ is called a "constant of proportionality": you are told that $C$ is proportional to $d^2$, symbolically written as $C \propto d^2$, which is equivalent to saying that $C=kd^2$, where $k$ is a constant (that you have to find).

Comment: Could I ask what context proportional is being used,  as this bit that is confusing me

Comment: Saying "$y$ is proportional to $x$" essentially tells you that doubling $x$ will cause $y$ to be doubled as well; it doesn't matter what the starting value is. Say,for example, that $y=10$ corresponds to $x=3$. If you are told $x=6$, then $y=20$.

Essentially, things increase in proportion to one another.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense And where did 13 come from :'(

Comment: When the diameter is $2$, it's square is $4$. So your information tells you that a pond with diameter $4$ costs £52 to build, so it costs £13 per "square diameter" to build.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24174/discussion-between-user243638-and-ken-wei).

Answer (score 2):

The problem statement says the cost $C$ is proportional to $d^2$ (the square of the diameter). There must exist a constant $A$ such that $$C = Ad^2$$ This is simply all it means for two things to be directly proportional. Raising $d$ to the power of the cost does not make any sense if you think about it. What would this accomplish? You are given that the value $d=2$ corresponds to a cost $C$ of $52$. If you plug this into the equation you simply get $$52 = A\cdot 2^2$$ This is enough information to solve for $A$, and hence you'll have all the information you need to calculate the cost of a pond given any value of $d$.

Answer (score 2):

"The cost, $C$, of building a circular pond is proportional to [something]" means $C = \alpha$[something] for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

In this case, the [something] is "the square of its diameter, d", i.e. $d^2$.
Thus we have $C = \alpha d^2$ for some $\alpha$.

Next we solve for $\alpha$ using that $52 = \alpha 2^2$,  so $\alpha = 52/4 = 13$.

Thus $C = 13d^2$.